# Converting String dictionary like to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have string that looks like dictionary like this:

```
{"h":"hello"}
```

I would like to convert it to an actual dictionary as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> s = "{'h':'hello'}"
>>> json.load(s)
```

Yet, I got an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py",
>   line 286, in load
>       return loads(fp.read(),
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

What is wrong to my code, and how I convert string like dictionary to actual dictionary? Thanks.

Comment: `json.load` is for a file, but thats not valid `json` anyway so `json.loads` wont work

Comment: For person who voted to close as typo: This is not off topic typo because it is valid python, just not valid json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `loads` instead of `load`:

```
json.loads(s)
```

`loads` take as input an string while `load` takes a readeable object (mostly a file)

Also json uses double quotes for quoting `'"'`

```
s = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/QuizzicalDistantSockeyesalmon)

Comment: thanks very much it's working fine :)

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted, since the input string uses single quotes, not double quotes. The answers using `ast.literal_eval()` are correct.

Comment: @Barmar, but also I think we need to take into account that the OP wanted to use `json.`  The error on quotes is explained in the answer as well :)

Comment: Unless they have control over the source data, what they "want" is irrelevant. They're stuck with what they get.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `ast.literal_eval` for this:

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval('{"h":"hello"}')  # {'h': 'hello'}
```

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/9209546) for why you should use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "{'h':'hello'}"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
{'h': 'hello'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` function allows you to run code and use the result. 
It is typically used to interprete a string as code.

```
string = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
dct = eval(string)
```

For more information on `eval`, see [the W3school explanatino on `eval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Disclaimer: if you are building a website for a broad user group, inform yoursel fon [Code injection risks of `eval` before using it.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Direct_Dynamic_Code_Evaluation_(%27Eval_Injection%27))

Comment: If you look in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/988251/1219006 It states not to use `eval`